# Change button to disabled with jQuery based on condition?

Tags: jquery

I just started learning jQuery and I'm watching video tutorials and trying to find different ways to accomplish things than in the video tutorial for learning purposes.

I have two buttons, Day and Night. If I click Day, I want the Day button to be disabled and to load the day style sheet. If I click Night, I want to load the Night stylesheet and disable the Night button, but then enable the Day button.

Bear with me, here's my code, ihavenoideawhatimdoing.jpg. This isn't my full code, only posted relevant code.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="day.css">
</head>

<button data-file="day">Day</button>
<button data-file="night">Night</button>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

    // self executing function
    (function() {
        var link = $('link');
        var button = $('button');
        var $this = $(this);

        if (button.data('file', 'day').click()) {
            link.attr('href', 'night.css');
            $this.attr('disabled');
            // code to enable night button, not sure how
        }
        else (button.data('file', 'night').click()) {
            link.attr('href', 'day.css');
            $this.attr('disabled');
            // code to enable the day button, not sure how
        }
    })();

</script>
```

Also, another question.

```
(function() {
    // code
})();
```

Will that function execute upon page load, I mean any code within that function? I think the guy in the video called it an autonomous function.

Thanks!

Comment: you a missing a `$` . `(function() {` should be `$(function() {`

Comment: Actually the autonomous function will execute itself immediately, not on page load. That's why you use jQuery's document ready function.

Comment: Apparently you don't need the $. I originally had the script that was shown in the video and it worked fine as is, so you don't need the $. Check the video: `http://tutsplus.com/lesson/events-101/` at 16:40

Comment: I suppose it will be fine as long as you have your script at the bottom of the page.

Comment: When a stylesheet is loaded, just changing the href will not make it "unloaded", and just because a function executes it self and you don't need to wrap it in a jQuery ready function, does'nt guarantee that jQuery will be loaded before your script runs.

Comment: @fudgey and @eveo You do need the $, if you use `$(function() {})` then it is the same as document ready [.ready function](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="day.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<button id="day" disabled>Day</button>
<button id="night">Night</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var link = $('link[href="day.css"]'),
            buttons = $('button');
        buttons.on('click', function() {
            link.attr('href', this.id+'.css');
            buttons.not(this).removeAttr('disabled');
            $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        });
    });
</script>​
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/PfbaK/), you can see the stylesheet change in your console.

Comment: Replace `link.attr('href', this.id+'.css');` with `link.attr('href', $(this).data('file')+'.css');` and it works.

Answer (score 1):

The `.click` statement will trigger a click on the element. Pass a function to it after selecting the element to trigger that function every time the event occurs.

```
(function() {
    var link = $('link');
    var button = $('button');
    var $this = $(this); // not sure what this is, so will need to be updated

    button.click(function () {
        if (button.data('file', 'day')) {
            $('#day-button').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#night-button').removeAttr('disabled');
            link.attr('href', 'night.css');
        } else {
            $('#day-button').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#night-button').attr('disabled', true);
            link.attr('href', 'day.css');
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: won't that change all of the link items on the page? if multiple style sheets are in play this could go wrong.  maybe `$("link[href='day.css']")` instead?

Answer (score 0):

The function will not execute by itself. You have to put that within document ready (gets executed when the page loads.)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    (function() {
        var link = $('link');
        var button = $('button');
        var $this = $(this);

        if (button.data('file', 'day').click()) {
            link.attr('href', 'night.css');
            $this.attr('disabled');
            // code to enable night button, not sure how
        }
        else (button.data('file', 'night').click()) {
            link.attr('href', 'day.css');
            $this.attr('disabled');
            // code to enable the day button, not sure how
        }
    })();
});
```

Comment: to answer the second question by the OP `$(function(){ ... });` is functionally equivalent to `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`

Comment: read again... he does not say $(function(){}); but (function(){})();